# File size of html web page generated

Tags: html, django, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a Django project locally . How can i find the size of webpage getting loaded in KiloBytes? How many bytes did the server rendered to the browser? 
I am using chrome. Please tell any trick to find this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Network** tab.

[image]

The top number in the size column is the size on the wire, generally this is a compressed size after gzip (and the only number that matters). The gray number is the content size originally before it was compressed on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can do this with the developers tools:

1. Right click and choose `Inspect Element`.
2. Go to `Network` tab.
3. F5 to reload

Answer (score 0):

The development server reports the size of each request served in the console.